# Duplicate zip entry in Proguard with Scala on Android

Tags: android, scala, sbt, android-proguard

I have the following error:

```
  Copying resources from program jar [D:\Users\antona\.ivy2\cache\org.scala-lang
\scala-library\jars\scala-library-2.12.4.jar] (filtered)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last android:proguard for the full output.
[error] (android:proguard) java.io.IOException: Can't write [D:\Work\scala\andro
id_scala_prooooject\target\android\intermediates\proguard\classes.proguard.jar]
(Can't read [D:\Users\antona\.ivy2\cache\org.scala-lang\scala-library\jars\scala
-library-2.12.4.jar(;;;;;;!META-INF/**,!rootdoc.txt)] (Duplicate zip entry [scal
a-library-2.12.4.jar:scala/annotation/compileTimeOnly.class]))
[error] Total time: 144 s, completed Nov 24, 2017 3:14:53 PM
```

I tried to remove references to scala-library, nothing helps. I do not understand the problem: rootdoc.txt? or compileTimeOnly.class?

This is my build.sbt:

```
scalacOptions += "-Yresolve-term-conflict:package"

proguardOptions in Android ++=
    "-dontnote" ::
    "-dontobfuscate" ::
    "-dontshrink" ::
    "-dontwarn InnerClasses,EnclosingMethod" ::
    "-dontwarn scala.annotation.compileTimeOnly" ::
    "-ignorewarnings" ::
    "-keepattributes InnerClasses,EnclosingMethod" ::
    "-dontoptimize" ::
    Nil

mappings in (Compile, packageBin) ~= { _.filter(!_._1.getName.endsWith(".txt")) }
```

I am using Scala 2.12.4

Answer (score 0):

Manually deleting scala/annotation/compileTimeOnly.class from scala-library-2.12.4.jar fixed the problem.